# how to perform navigation[segue] from midle of the flow + ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, segue

im working on a Navigation based application. i have used Story board to design my interfaces. and i use login functionality too. so in app delegate class im checking weather the user has loged in , according to the login state im loading either Home page or login page.

my problem is , when i open a view controller like that , my other functions not working.

such as , i have a button in home page which is push to a another view. when the app is launch from Home, the button is not working.[does not push to the desired view ]. so i tried it programmatically but that did not worked as well.

so here is how my story board looks like[image]

here is my app delegate code which is open the app according to login status

```
NSUserDefaults* userinfo = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString* customer =[userinfo stringForKey:@"username"];

if((customer!=nil)){
    //redirect to diferent pages
   // DetailPageClass *detailPage = [[DetailPageClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailPageClass" bundle:nil];
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    Home *home = (Home *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];
    //LoginView *login = (LoginView *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
    home.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    self.window.rootViewController = home;
    [self.navController pushViewController:home animated:YES];
}else{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    LoginView *login = (LoginView *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
    login.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    self.window.rootViewController = login;
    [self.navController pushViewController:login animated:YES];
}
```

and i was trying to push to the views like below (programmatically)

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
SignUp *login = (SignUp *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signUp"];
//UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login];
// [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
[self.nav pushViewController:login animated:YES];
```

can someone tell me how to do this in a correct way. and what is the issue i got here..please help me

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `window.rootViewController` to be the `navController`, this should work.

Comment: So the other function still doesn't work? `UINavigationController *navCtl = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = navCtl; [navCtl pushViewController:home animated:YES];` and this worked for me.

Comment: i got this error :  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.

Comment: That is because the controller doing the push is not on a navigation stack, nav->A->B->C, this will work fine, A->B->C will cause trouble, you need to check that if the controller's navigation controller is nil by logging out `self.navigationController`.

Comment: what if the self.navigationControler is nill ? what should i do ?

Comment: See the comment above, window's rootViewController is a navigation controller. so home's navigationController will not be nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64934/discussion-between-darshana-and-gabbler).